# Data in XML: where to place it

Tags: android, mysql, xml

I am trying to design a new Android application.
For that application I will have an XML file that will be located somewhere on the server. This file will be generated from the mySQL DB.

For now (developmental phase) I got a simple and small XML file that I need to put in the Android Eclipse project in order to read it and present the data on the phone.

I just tried to put this file in res/values, but compiler gives me an error: "Invalid start tag".
Looking through the stackoverflow and google I see a lot of different answers and google even give me an answer of how to parse xml file on Android. ;-)

So is there a "standard" place where such XML file goes in Android Eclipse project? Think about it as the data that is read from the DB.

Some answers are to place it in the res/xml folder. I just made a brand new Android project and I don't see such folder in it. Do I create one? Shouldn't it be done automatically?

Some says you need to put it the res/raw folder. Again it is not present in the Eclipse project. Do I make one? Shouldn't it be present already?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be present already?

It doesn't have to. There can be thousands of folders inside res/ folder. You don't want to have them all at first.

> Do I make one?

Yes. Add folders when you need them.

> Some answers are to place it in the res/xml folder.
>
> Some says you need to put it the res/raw folder.

The difference between these folders is that files inside raw stay the same you put them and inside xml are parsed when APK is created and put there in a binary, optimized form, similar to what happens to layouts, AndroidManifest and other.